# New column based on list of values SQL

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and working on a database that needs a binary indicator based on the presence of string values in a column. I'm trying to make a new table as follows:

Original:

| Indicator |
| --- |
| a, b, c |
| c, d, e |

Desired:

| Indicator | type |
| --- | --- |
| a, b, c | 1 |
| c, d, e | 0 |

SQL code:

```
SELECT 
      ID, 
      Contract, 
      Indicator,
      CASE 
         WHEN Indicator IN ('a', 'b')
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
      END as Type
INTO new_table
FROM old_table
```

The table I keep creating reports every type as 0.

I also have 200+ distinct indicators, so it will be really time-consuming to write each as:

```
CASE 
   WHEN Indicator = 'a' THEN '1'
   WHEN Indicator = 'b' THEN '1'
```

Is there a more streamlined way to think about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome SO @code-for-your-life Why do you need to create another table? It sounds, for me, that you can go with a view...

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! The final vision is to join this table with two others, making a streamlined table to bring into Looker (which is what my organization is choosing to use as the BI tool). But I can't get this table to do what I need it to.

Comment: What DBMS you are using?

Comment: One can query views and join them like normal tables. :) The problem with calculated values is that you do it once, at each query (of course there can be chaching) but once your initial tables updated the new ones need to be rebuild, so if you go extra tables way you need triggers and stored procedures etc.

Comment: I'm on SQL Server Management Studio. I'll look into query views, since that sounds so useful!! Thank you for the information and pointing me in a direction that I can learn from!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first step is to understand why your code doesn’t work right now.

If your examples of what’s Indicator column are literally the strings you noted (a, b, c in one string and c, d, e in another) you should understand that your case statement is saying “I am looking for an exact match on the full value of Indicator against the following list -

1. The letter A or
2. The letter B

Essentially- you are saying “hey SQL, does ‘a,b,c’ match to ‘a’? Or does  ‘a,b,c’ match to ‘b’. ?”

Obviously SQL’s answer is “these don’t match” which is why you get all 0s.

You can try wildcard matching with the LIKE syntax.

Case when Indicator like ‘%a%’ or Indicator like ‘%b%’ then 1 else 0 end as Type

Now, if the abc and cde strings aren’t REALLY what’s in your database then this approach may not work well for you.

Example, let’s say your real values are words that are all slapped together in a single string.

Let’s say that your strings are 3 words each.

1. Cat, Dog, Man
2. Catalog, Stick, Shoe
3. Hair, Hellcat, Belt

And let’s say that Cat is a value that should cause Type to be 1.

If you write: case when Indicator like ‘%cat%’ then 1 else 0 end as Type - all 3 rows will get a 1 because the wildcard will match Cat in Catalog and cat in Hellcat.

I think the bottom line is that unless your Indicator values really are 3 letters and your match criteria is a single letter, you very well could be better off writing a 200 line long case statement if you need this done any time soon.

A better approach to consider (depending on things like are you going to have 300 different combinations a week or month or year from now?)

If yes, wouldn’t it be nice if you had a table with a total of 6 rows - like so?

Indicator | Indictor_Parsed

a,b,c | a

a,b,c | b

a,b,c | c

c,d,e | c

c,d,e | d

c,d,e | e

Then you could write the query as you have it case when Indicator_Parsed in (‘a’, ‘b’) then 1 else 0 end as Type - as a piece of a more verbose solution.

If this approach seems useful to you, here’s a link to the page that lets you parse those comma-separated-values into additional rows. [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: Wow, Gavin!! Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. This makes total sense why I'm not getting what I'm looking for. My true indicators are more like E.241 and C.984, so I'll probably just have to write it out, then.

Answer (score 0):

ON mysql/sql server You can do it as follows :

```
insert into table2
select Indicator,
  CASE WHEN Indicator like '%a%' or Indicator like '%b%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As type
from table1;
```

[demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Iyuta0Nz)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `REGEXP` operator to check for presence of either a, b or both.

```
SELECT Indicator,
       Indicator REGEXP '.*[ab].*'
FROM tab
```

If you need that into a table, you either create it from scratch

```
CREATE your_table AS 
SELECT Indicator,
       Indicator REGEXP '.*[ab].*'
FROM tab
```

or you insert values in it:

```
INSERT INTO your_table
SELECT Indicator,
       Indicator REGEXP '.*[ab].*'
FROM tab
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rDWWZNFNwjcAKgN73xqjcN/0).